# Validate a Collection Field Type in Symfony 2 with allowExtraFields=true

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to validate a collection form field:

```
$builder->add(
  'autor',
  'collection',
  array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'options' => array('required' => false),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'error_bubbling' => false
  )
);
```

I use JavaScript, as suggested in the Cookbook, to dynamically add more text fields to the collection. My problem is, that I don't know, how to validate these fields. The collection validator lets me validate specific fields of a collection by their name but not simply every field of it. How can I manage that?

Even cooler would be, if I could check, if **at least** one of the fields is `notBlank` instead of forcing it to every field.

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "constraints" option defined in form Field Type that are available on all fields.(http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html#constraints).
In your case, you can add your constraint like this:

```
$builder->add('autor', 'collection', array(
                        'constraints' => new NotBlank()),
           ));
```

(in this case dont forget to include the constraints provided by the Validation component:
`use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;` ...)

i didnt test but i think with this every input will be validate againts the constraint you assigned to the field, and as you have the option "error_bubbling" as false, an error message should be attached to the invalid element.

**--EDIT--**

Since you even use the 2.0 version of Symfony i think this solution solves your problem, however I strongly advise you to update to the 2.3 version.

You can create a Form Event Subscriber(http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) that will be listening the POST_BIND event.(note that Post Bind event is Deprecated since version 2.3 and will be removed in 3.0);

In your subscriber class, you will validate each of your submited authors as you want and add an error to the form if something is wrong.

Your postBind method could be something like this:

```
public function postBind(DataEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();

        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        // get the submited values for author
        // author is an array
        $author = $form['autor']->getData();

       // now iterate over the authors and validate what you want
       // if you find any error, you can add a error to the form like this:
       $form->addError(new FormError('your error message'));

       // now as the form have errors it wont pass on the isValid() method 
       // on your controller. However i think this error wont appear 
       // next to your invalid author input but as a form error, but with
       // this you can unsure that non of the fields will be blank for example.

    }
```

you can check the Symfony2 Form Component API if you have any doubt about a core method.
http://api.symfony.com/2.0/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately I forgot to mention, that at the moment I'm running Symfony 2.0, so the `constraints` option isn't yet available. Upgrading to 2.3 is scheduled for after implementing this author functionality. Is there another possible solution or do I have to convince my boss, that postponing this after the upgrade would be a better idea?

Comment: I think you should update to version 2.3 because it is a stable version that will be supported over the next three years instead of version 2.0 that is no longer supported. However I'll look for a solution that fits better on you and soon i will put it here.

Comment: @GrimReaper1908 check my edit. I think the solution will guide you if you follow this path.